# Magento Varnish Turpentine By Pass a Block (dont cached a block)

Tags: magento, varnish

I am testing magento with varnish and turpentine extesion. I installed all successfully but when i try to by pass (or flush per second) a block, it is hidden or disapear.

For Example i want to by pass product.info.media block.

My xml configuration for by pass in turpenine_esi.xml :

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.media">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>public</access>
                <ttl>1</ttl>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The block is:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />
</block>
```

is possible to do this? I'm doing wrong?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try next:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.media">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <method>esi</method>
                <access>public</access>
                <scope>page</scope>
                <ttl>1</ttl>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Also check what your block inherit from Mage_Core_Block_Template class.

Comment: Hi, thank for the answer. That dont work, the block disappear. The block inherit from Mage_Core_Block_Template. I dont know what happen but with the header and footer works perfect :S

Comment: Block parent classes: array (size=5)
  'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract' => string 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract' (length=40)
  'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract' => string 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract' (length=35)
  'Mage_Core_Block_Template' => string **'Mage_Core_Block_Template'** (length=24)
  'Mage_Core_Block_Abstract' => string 'Mage_Core_Block_Abstract' (length=24)
  'Varien_Object' => string 'Varien_Object' (length=13)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off putting your ESI options in the *local.xml* for your theme, since *turpentine_esi.xml* may get overwritten when you update the extension.

Turn on debugging in Turpentine and see if anything interesting shows up in your system.log. Other caching extensions or having other caches enabled can cause errors like these. Also, check for exceptions being generated from your template, those can also cause issues like this.